# Get PathTwo Counts In Dynamic PathOne

Tags: powershell

I need to find all the PathTwos in PathOne under the directory Path; currently I can get all the PathOne's by using:

```
$path = Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Since PathOne is dynamic (it's name may be anything), this helps me loop through all the possible paths.  Now, PathOne may have 2 or more folders, like PathTwo1, PathTwo2 and PathTwo3.  I need to know how many folders are in the dynamic PathOne.  Originally I thought that I could loop within PathOne, get the name of the dynamic path and then loop through PathOne, counting all the PathTwos and return everything over 1; unfortunately that doesn't return what I need.

I've tried:

- A loop within a loop: creates a mess and doesn't return the correct result.
- Use `C:\Path\.\` to get the count of the folders within PathOne, by jumping to whatever the next folder would be.

Based on comments, example:

```
C:\Path\PathOne1\PathTwo1
C:\Path\PathOne1\PathTwo2
C:\Path\PathOne2\PathTwo1
C:\Path\PathOne2\PathTwo2
C:\Path\PathOne2\PathTwo3
C:\Path\PathOne3\PathTwo1 # don't want because only one PathTwo
```

I don't care how many PathOnes there are, but I do need every PathOne that has more than one PathTwos.

Comment: Are you looking for folders at arbitrary hierarchy levels? Or just immediate children of the parent path? Is "PathTwo" just a (partial) folder name, or can it be a partial path (like `foo\bar`)?

Comment: I think I get it...... but it might help if you need to show a simple directory structure and what you expect to get. Could also help if you show your current counting logic.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks; you killed two birds with one stone, I was just trying to figure out how to jump paths, but that does the count too.  Thanks again.  I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get desired result by this command:

```
# Get all items on two level deep.
Get-Item C:\Path\*\* |
# Get only directories.
Where-Object PSIsContainer |
# Group them by parent.
Group-Object {$_.Parent.FullName} -NoElement |
# Choose groups with Count more then one.
Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
# Select name of parent directory
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```